# Parameters - geographic transformation - ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, parameters

Is there a way to know what parameters  are set for any geographic transformation in ArcGIS?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is an extensive list to be found for [ArcMap](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/projections/pdf/geographic_transformations.pdf) and for [ArcGIS Pro](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/properties/pdf/geographic_transformations.pdf).

An alternative is the GitHub repo, [Esri projection engine database documentation](https://github.com/Esri/projection-engine-db-doc).

Comment: I know link-only answers are discouraged here, but I really wouldn't know what else to add. If the link goes down, just search for *ArcGIS Geographic and Vertical Transformation Tables*